# Approximation to solution of a finite sum equation

Tags: sequences-and-series

In [Principles of Population Genetics](http://www.sinauer.com/principles-of-population-genetics.html) I encountered the equation

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{2 N}\right)^t = \sum_{i=1}^t \frac{1}{2 x_i}\tag{1}$$

, where all $N$, $t$ and all $x_i$'s are strictly positive natural numbers. From this equation, the authors say that $N$ is the harmonic mean of $[x_1, x_2, ...,x_{t-1},x_t]$. In other words, the following should be derivable from `(1)`

$$\frac{1}{N} = \frac{1}{t} \sum_{i=1}^t \frac{1}{x_i}\tag{2}$$

This second equation might be true only as an approximation (for large $N$ for example). I failed to prove this true.

**Can you help me to prove that (2) results (directly or via an approximation) from (1)?**

Comment: Mathjax issue: The only solution I found to number my equations was to add a number of `\space`  before `(n)`. I very welcome editing to improve that. Thnks

Comment: Do the authors give any conditions on the $x_i$'s?

Comment: @BenS. I forgot this info (question now edited). All variables ($t$, $N$ and all $x_i$) are strictly positive natural numbers. Thanks

Comment: For $t = 1$ the first equation becomes $1-\tfrac{1}{2N} = \tfrac{1}{2x_1}$ while the second equation becomes $\tfrac{1}{N} = \tfrac{1}{x_1}$. These are not equivalent unless $x_1 = 1$.

Comment: Use `\tag{1}` to add the `(1)` at the right margin.  I've edited the post to use `\tag`

Answer (score 1):

It's not that it follows from $(1)$, it just follows from the definition of harmonic mean which you can find here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean

In other words,
$N=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{t} \sum_{i=1}^{t} \frac{1}{x_i}}$, so $\frac{1}{N}=\frac{1}{t} \sum_{i=1}^{t} \frac{1}{x_i}$

Answer (score 0):

If $N$ is large in relation to $t$, then we can use the approximation

$\displaystyle\;\;\;\bigg(1-\frac{1}{2N}\bigg)^t=1-\frac{t}{2N}+\binom{t}{2}\big(-\frac{1}{2N}\big)^2+\cdots\approx1-\frac{t}{2N}$

to get $\displaystyle1-\frac{t}{2N}\approx\sum_{i=1}^{t}\frac{1}{2x_i},\;$ so $\;\;\displaystyle \frac{2}{t}-\frac{1}{N}\approx\frac{1}{t}\sum_{i=1}^t\frac{1}{x_i}$ and $\;\displaystyle\frac{1}{N}\approx\frac{2}{t}-\frac{1}{t}\sum_{i=1}^t\frac{1}{x_i}$

(which doesn't agree with what the authors claim).